# Finding running pod per node in GCP using Metrics Explorer

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, azure-aks

I am working on shifting from AKS to GKE.
In AKS it is very easy to find running pods per Node using below KQL.

```
KubePodInventory
| summarize count() by Computer
```

However I am not able to find same in GKE in GCP using Metrics Explorer. Need help

Answer (score 0):

Menu > Monitoring > Dashboards > GKE Compute Resources - Node View >  Number of Pods per Node

In MQL(Monitoring Query Language):

```
fetch k8s_pod
| metric 'kubernetes.io/pod/network/received_bytes_count'
|  filter true() 
|  filter true() 
|  filter true() 
| align rate(1m)
| every 1m
| group_by [resource.project_id, resource.location, resource.cluster_name, resource.namespace_name, resource.pod_name, metadata.system.node_name],
    [value_received_bytes_count_mean: pick_any(value.received_bytes_count)]
    | group_by [metadata.system.node_name], [row_count()]
```